# Write a C function GetEvenNumber

Tags: c

For my studies, I have to write a C function `GetEvenNumber`:

- parameters: array with n integers + array size;
- returns `tr` array which contains even integers from `td`.

I don't know a priori the length of the array `tr`.

My below code returns errors:

```
#include <stdio.h> // define the header file  

int *GetEvenNumber(int t[], int size)
{
    int tr[];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (t[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("%d is even \n", t[i]);
            tr[j] = t[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return tr;
}

int main()   // define the main function  
{   
    int *t; // = {4, 3, 1, 8, 6 };
    int *tr = GetEvenNumber(t, 5);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d \n", tr[i]);
}
```

I get error:

```
error: array size missing in 'tr'
     int tr[];

warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return tr;
```

How do I fix that? Thanks.

Comment: `int t[]` decays into a pointer to `int` when defined as a parameter in the function, but is not the same case inside the body of a function, in this case you need to define the size of the array: `int tr[size];` or `int *tr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);`

Comment: Can't use a vla as op want to return it.

Comment: Thanks but at this step of my course I didn't see dynamic allocation (malloc)  so I can't use it.

Comment: Then you can't return a new array.  You will need to pass an array, or modify the one you pass in.  Update question with new restrictions please.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you could not use `malloc()` to dynamically create  `tr` within `GetEvenNumber()` to address the two issues raised by your copmiler.  This leaves making `tr` a global variable, or as here pass in the result array `tr` to be filled out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void GetEvenNumber(size_t size, const int *td, size_t *size2, int *tr) {
    *size2 = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
        if(td[i] % 2 == 0)
            tr[(*size2)++] = td[i];
}

int main() {
    int td[] = {4, 3, 1, 8, 6 };
    size_t size = sizeof(td) / sizeof(*td);
    int tr[size];
    size_t size2;
    GetEvenNumber(size, td, &size2, tr);
    for (size_t i=0; i < size2; i++)
        printf("%d \n", tr[i]);
}
```

If the input array `td` contains uneven elements, then the result array `tr` have fewer valid elements than the input.  I used `size2` here to tell caller how many elements are valid in `tr`.  Your code did not assign any values to, in this example, last 3 elements.  You don't tell us what should happen with those last elements.

In modern C, if you specify the size before the array in the argument, then you can use the size in array specification which help document what is going on.

Comment: Thanks. In output I have:  0 is even
4194304 is even
1999068544 is even
859472 is even . It seems to be adresses resuts and not the integers..

Comment: Did you initialize `t` in `main()`?  Your original was operating on uninitialized memory which may cause garbage output.

Comment: Good point re const.  Fixed.  C99 was released in May 2000.  22 years is a LONG time.  I think it's clearer keeping the two output arguments together but your suggestion is valid too.

Comment: @chqrlie Fine! Be that way (supposed to be funny)  Changed as suggested, thanks.

Comment: @chqrlie Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again.  Argh... slipped through when I was experimenting eliminating `i` in favor of decrementing size and incrementing the pointer.   Didn't seem worth it but only partially reverted to what I had tested initially.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to

> int tr[];

because you have to specify the size of your array during its creation.

I suggest trying to add a function that returns the number of even numbers in the array:

```
int getEvenNum(int t[], int lent){
   int numEven = 0;                     // initialize counter to zero
   for(int i = 0; i < lent; i++){     // for each element of the array
      if ((t[i] % 2) == 0){             // if it's even,
         numEven++;                     // add 1 to counter
      }
   }
   return(numEven);                     // finaly returns the value of the counter
}
```

and then you replace the `int tr[];` by `int tr[getEvenNum(t, size)];` (maybe there's a `;` after the `getEvenNum(t, size)` but I'm not sure)

Comment: `sizeof(t)` will evaluate to the size of an `int` pointer, not that of the array. The array length must be passed as a separate argument.

Comment: You should work on your understanding of the C syntax. The `;` after the body of the `if` and the `for` are useless. So are the parentheses around the `return` value.

Comment: Yes I know -- but I'm never sure of wether there is the `;` or not (sorry).

Comment: The `sizeof()` error is much more problematic. Your answer must be fixed. As posted it is incorrect and misleading: it deserves a downvote.

Comment: And I'll correct the size-of-the-array problem.

Comment: It's fixed now. And for the parenthesis around the return value, I put them to make it clear what's the value (even if it's useless. It makes the code smarter)

Comment: OK. There is still a problem with your approach: if there are no even numbers in the array, `getEvenNum` will return `0`, which is an invalid value for the length of the VLA in `main` defined as `int tr[getEvenNum(t, size)];` For the sake of this exercise, defining an array `tr` with the same length as that of `t` is acceptable. The focus is on copying even numbers from one array to the other using separate index variables.

Answer (score 1):

Since the array **tr** can have AT MOST the same number of elements as the original integer array, it would be safe to declare the array with the same size as the array 't[]'.

I have made some changes to your code. Try the following:

```
#include<stdio.h> // define the header file

void GetEvenNumber(int *t, int* tr, int size, int *pCountEven)
{
    int i, j=0;

    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(t[i]%2==0)
        {
            printf("%d is even \n", t[i]);
            tr[j++] = t[i];

        }
    }
    *pCountEven = j;
}

int main()   // define the main function
{
    int t[] = {4, 3, 1, 8, 6 };
    int tr[5], countEven = 0, i;
    GetEvenNumber(t, tr, 5, &countEven);

    for (i=0; i < countEven; i++)
        printf("%d\n", tr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: As @chqrlie (who is an experienced coder) pointed out, we can simply return the length of the array instead of taking the address of a variable.
So alternatively, you can try this:

```
#include <stdio.h> // define the header file

int GetEvenNumber(int *t, int *tr, int size) {
    int i, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (t[i] % 2 == 0) {
            printf("%d is even \n", t[i]);
            tr[j++] = t[i];
        }
    }
    return j;
}

int main()   // define the main function
{
    int t[] = { 4, 3, 1, 8, 6 };
    int tr[5], countEven = 0, i;
    countEven = GetEvenNumber(t, tr, 5);

    for (i = 0; i < countEven; i++)
        printf("%d\n", tr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right. That works, too. We can simply return 'j' at the end of the function and store it in the main() within "countEven" variable. That should do the job.